# How to set icon position over image in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to put a icon over an image.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
}

.des {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="item">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/g33.jpg" alt="Avatar">
        <div class="des">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title ">Farwa Waheed</h5>
        <p class="card-text" style="font-size:13px;"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I expect the output to be icon at the left bottom side over image but actual  output : the icon is coming down from the picture

Comment: Yes. But how to use it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS like below. You can also change the position of image by changing the value of the `left` or `bottom`.

```
.item {
  position: relative;
}

.des {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

If it does not work. Let me know.